# Angular Services Lifetime from User Perspective

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some issues understanding how exactly services are handled from the users perspective.

When are services initialized? As singletons, do they span the application lifetime, or the current user / session?

Like, if i store an array inside the service, will this be available to all sessions, or only the current session?

And is this the same for components?

Comment: Define "session". You do realize that an Angular application executes inside the browser, right? And thus that every browser (tab) has a different Application instance from the other browsers?

Comment: No, i did not realize this. So any variables contained are completely isolated per browser.

Comment: Per tab of browser actually. It's client-side JavaScript code. Every time you open or refresh a tab, the application restarts from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of an instance of a class decorated with the `@Injectable` decorator depends on the scope of their parent injector. There are basically 3 levels of injector scopes:

- **root**: An instance injected via the application injector will only be initialized once at application start and will life throughout the application lifetime. They are basically singleton instances, but still can be injected into another scope (which will create a new instance for that scope).

Example:

```
 @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
 export class MyRootService
 {
 }
```

Another technique to create root scoped services is to import a `ModuleWithProviders`:

```
@NgModule()
export class MyModule
{
  public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders
  {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
        MyRootService,
      ],
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

- **module**: Instances that are injected by the module injector will live throughout their module lifetime. If that module is imported by one or more lazy loaded modules, an instance of that class for each module is created and will be destroyed if their module is destroyed.

Example:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: MyModule })
export class MyService
{
}

// or 

@Injectable()
export class MyService
{
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MyService,
  ],
})
export class MyModule
{
}
```

- **component**: If your service is part of the component's providers section, it will only live throughout the component's lifetime and with each component, a new instance is created.

Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService
{
}

@Component({
  providers: [
    MyService,
  ],
})
export class MyComponent
{
}
```

> The `providedIn` syntax is used to create tree-shakeable services, because the direction of dependencies is reversed, so your service will only be part of the application bundle if it's used somewhere in your code.

A more detailed explanation on Angular dependency injection can be found [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).